# TWIG - include variables in different template

Tags: twig

I would like to include the same variables in different templates

### vars_catchphrase.twig

```
{% set catchphrase_size = '' %}
{% if var.tile_catchphrase|length <= 4 %}
    {% set catchphrase_size = 'size-lg' %}
{% elseif var.tile_catchphrase|length >= 5 and var.tile_catchphrase|length <= 8 %}
    {% set catchphrase_size = 'size-md' %}
{% elseif var.tile_catchphrase|length >= 9 and var.tile_catchphrase|length <= 12 %}
    {% set catchphrase_size = 'size-sm' %}
{% elseif var.tile_catchphrase|length >= 13 %}
    {% set catchphrase_size = 'size-xs' %}
{% endif %}
```

I tried to include with this (because the context is sometime different) :

```
{% include 'vars_catchphrase.twig' with { 'var' : post } %}
```

When the context is different from `post` I use another one :

```
{% include 'vars_catchphrase.twig' with { 'var' : item } %}
```

### example.twig

```
{% for item in list %}
    {% include 'vars_catchphrase.twig' with { 'var' : item } %}

    <p class="catchphrase {{ catchphrase_size }}">{{ item.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The variable is empty. Can I have some help please ?

Comment: maybe 'var' variable is an array, not an object.

Comment: var["tile_catchphrase"] insetad of var.tile_catchphrase

Comment: @danielarend doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates you include have their own variable scope, this means variables defined inside this template will not be known out the template. This said, included templates also can't alter the parent's context (by default), this is due to `twig` passing the context array by value, not by reference.

*foo.twig*

```html
{% set foo = 'foo' %}
{% include 'bar.twig' %}
{{ foo }}
```

*bar.twig*

```html
{% set foo = 'bar' %}
```

The [example](https://twigfiddle.com/pmuzdb) above will still output `foo`

---

In order to solve your problem, I'd suggest adding a custom filter to `twig`

```php
<?php
    $twig->addFilter(new \Twig\TwigFilter('catchphrase_size', function($value) {
        switch(true) {
            case strlen($value->tile_catchphrase) >= 13: return 'size-xs';
            case strlen($value->tile_catchphrase) >= 9: return 'size-sm';
            case strlen($value->tile_catchphrase) >= 5: return 'size-md';
            default: return 'size-lg';
        }
    });
```

This way you can use the filter where ever,

```html
{% for item in list %}
    <p class="catchphrase {{ item|catchphrase_size }}">{{ item.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is the best clean solution ! I still have a lot of progress to do with TWIG. Thank you again for your help !