# How to correctly pass a variable from a twig include file to another include twig file

Tags: javascript, twig, templating-engine, twig.js

I am trying to pass a variable from one twig include file to another twig include file, (I did post earlier but my question probably wasn't as clear as it could have been). I have 3 files, the `view.twig` & then a `gallery.twig` & `galleryConfig.twig` files

I somehow need to extract the variables from the `galleryConfig.twig` file and have these available to the `gallery.twig` file - I know how to pass a variable directly into the template using the `with` - but how would I use this to pass ALL the variables from `galleryConfig.twig` into the `gallery.twig` file

view.twig

```
<div>
  {% include '@app/components/view/images/galleryConfig.twig' %}
  {% include '@app/components/view/images/gallery.twig' with {
      'holdingImage' : 'somefile.png'
  } %}       
</div>
```

galleryConfig.twig

```
{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
          
    </script>
{% endblock %}
{% set holdingImage = ('holding-image.svg') %}
```

gallery.twig

```
{% block content %}
<div>
  {{ holdingImage }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Expected result :
The gallery.twig view to display the `holdingImage` variable which is `holding-image.svg` and stored in the `galleryConfig.twig` file

Comment: As I've posted in your other question, this is not possible. Each include has its own scope. Variables are passed by value as well and not by reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TWIG - include variables in different template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64484376/twig-include-variables-in-different-template)

Comment: @DarkBee still learning TWIG & it is still in the confusing stage for me :)

Comment: No worries. If you provide more information on your angle or why you would want to do this I'd gladly help you out. Is using a twig extension an option for you? Then have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525041/can-a-twig-simplefunction-modify-the-context)